# what does the following assembly code do? I need to write a code that checks if shift button has been pressed

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
  PUSH AX
  MOV AH , 12h
  INT 16h
  AND AX,3
  CMP AX,3 ;;; bit 0 = R-shift    bit 1 = L-shift
  JE ClickTwoShift
  POP AX
```

Comment: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1773.htm

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> MOV AH , 12h
> INT 16h
> ```

These instructions invoke the BIOS.GetKeyboardFlags function. It returns a result in the `AX` register.

> ```
> AND AX,3
> ```

Bit 0 tells if the right shift key is depressed.
Bit 1 tells if the left shift key is depressed.
By anding with 3 which is 0000_0000_0000_0011b in binary notation, we only keep those shift-related bits.

> ```
> CMP AX,3 ;;; bit 0 = R-shift    bit 1 = L-shift
> JE ClickTwoShift
> ```

If at this point the `AX` register is equal to 3, we know that both the left- and right shift keys were depressed.

---

You can see what all the returned bits mean by looking at http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_16-12.html

---

> ```
> PUSH AX
> MOV AH , 12h
> INT 16h
> AND AX,3
> CMP AX,3 ;;; bit 0 = R-shift    bit 1 = L-shift
> JE ClickTwoShift
> POP AX
> ```

The above code could have a problem with an unbalanced stack!
If we write the `pop ax` **before** conditionally jumping to *clickTwoShift* the code would not need a second `pop ax` somewhere on the *ClickTwoShift* path.

```
push    ax
mov     ah, 12h   ; BIOS.GetKeyboardFlags
int     16h       ; -> AX
and     ax, 0003h ; Only keeping 'shift' bits
cmp     ax, 0003h
pop     ax
je      ClickTwoShift
```